# How do you calculate the average of an array of arrays in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say we have the following:

```py
a = [(R1, G1, B1),
     (R2, G2, B2),
     (R3, G3, B3)]
```

How can I calculate the averages of the arrays and put it in a new array? Like the following:

```py
a = [(R, B, G)]
```

Where `R`, `G`, `B` are the averages of `R1`, `R2` and `R3` etc.

Comment: What have you attempted, and what difficulties have you faced?

Comment: @yatu totally forgot, kind of new here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done in a comprehension:

```
avgs = [sum(vals)/len(a) for vals in zip(*a)]
```

As an example:

```
>>> a = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
>>> avgs = [sum(vals)/len(a) for vals in zip(*a)]
>>> avgs
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(3,3)
y = x.mean(axis=0)
print(y)
```

Comment: @Will agree with you. But I'm guessing he is trying to work with image data(by looking at RGB notations). So its better to use numpy for these kind of tasks.

Comment: Why would that be?

Comment: By default images in opencv python are stored as numpy arrays.

Comment: yet OP doesn't mention opencv either

Comment: Yes, its just an assumption. Its upto the user to select the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
a = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
arr = np.array(a)
means = means = np.mean(arr, axis=0)
print(means)

# prints array([4., 5., 6.])
```

If you want to obtain the result in your format, i.e. list with just one tuple, you could do

```
result = [tuple(means)]
```